# Escaped HTML string in JSON invalid

Tags: json

I have a JSON with HTML code. I escaped all characters using [this tool.](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html) When validating the JSON I get

```
    Parse error on line 2:
{  "html": "<table class=\"MsoT
-----------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

When entered into postmans body I can see that the string is valid until certain point:
[image]

Full json: [here](https://pastebin.com/WQJ2RDMk)

I do not see any problem with the string. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Don't paste photos of your code. Paste your code.

Comment: I did. Under Full json: here

Comment: Can you show the code where you parsing the json. OR just try replacing \' to \"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a problem with the numerous double quotes within the HTML string since the basic JSON structure is {"key" : "value"}. Maybe you want to change your double quotes within the HTML string to to single quotes or some other character leaving something like {"html" : ""}.